# Issues with tailwind media queries

Tags: tailwind-css, breakpoints, font-size

This functions properly and causes the text to become larger at the small breakpoint (opposite of what I want)
`text-md sm:text-sm`

When I try and reverse it to get the desired effect the text size remaines "sm" for all breakpointes. Not behaving as I would expect.
`text-sm sm:text-md`

Am I doing something wrong here?

It's a simple p tag if that helps:

`<p className="text-center mb-8 text-md sm:text-sm">`

I've tried every combination of the breakpoint classes to get it to adjust properly with no success and couldn't find any specific enough information online

**Edit**
Oddly enough in the same project in another section `md:text-sm text-xs` works perfectly fine on it's p tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around it by using the scale class so no big deal

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind uses mobile first approach.
`sm:text-sm` will set the font size to small in `sm` as well as screens above the `sm` breakpoint.
what you need to do is use mobile first approach. So, set a default class for smaller breakpoints and apply media queries for larger breakpoints.

I would do something like this:

```
<p className="text-center mb-8 text-sm md:text-md ">
```

Comment: This behaves the same as the second example for some reason and causes the text to just remain small at all breakpoints.

I've tried every combination of that to my knowledge